# SL Out of browser app - SecurityException

Tags: silverlight-5.0, out-of-browser

My SL5 out-of-browser application works on one computer, but not on another computer.
On both computers the application is built in, and started from, VS2012 running as Administrator.
The SecurityException occurs here:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)
```

A possibly related issue:  On the computer that throws the exception, the app runs in the default browser, while on the other computer the app runs out-of-browser.

Any insights will be appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

The related issue is spot on: you can't access local folders with a standard Silverlight in browser app, but you can with an OOB one.

So you have either to restrict your functionality to Out-of-Browser mode or enable elevated priviledges in browser (which is quite painful, see various questions on SO: [search results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsilverlight-5.0%5D%20elevated%20browser)).

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Any idea on the first question:  Why does the OOB app run out-of-browser on one computer, but in-browser on the other?

Comment: If started from VisualStudio, it depends on your "startup project". If you select the app's project, it starts OOB, if you select the web project, it starts IB.

Comment: Thaks, but: 1) The app's project is the startup project, 2) There is no explicit web project.

Comment: Doh! I don't have a VS2012 handy with my Silverlight projects right now, so I can only make guesses. You've checked the Silverlight project settings, ie enable OOB, etc...?

Comment: Checked and double-checked, VS2012 is running as Administrator,etc.
Thanks for the reply.